# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') using nu.svc

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to run this code:

```
clf_i=svm.NuSVC
clf_ii=clf_i(kernel='linear')
selector = RFECV(clf_ii, step=1, cv=cv_i,n_jobs=jobs)                    
X = selector.fit_transform(X, y)
```

where clf_i is clf_i=svm.NuSVC
but I get this error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64')

when `clf_i=svm.SVC` I don't have any error on the same dataset. In both cases `cv_i = LeaveOneOut()` when I call 'selector' I have:

```
RFECV(cv=LeaveOneOut(),
estimator=NuSVC(cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
max_iter=-1, nu=0.5, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
n_jobs=-1, scoring=None, step=1, verbose=0)
```

in the first case 
and

```
RFECV(cv=LeaveOneOut(),
estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
tol=0.001, verbose=False), 
n_jobs=-1, scoring=None, step=1, verbose=0)
```

in the second case

I thought that there is something wrong with the parameters for the nu.SVC but I was not able to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Your data is having some blank values or string values. You should replace these with a int type

Comment: I have tried also with random generated arrays and got the same error

Comment: Also when I try to do the cross validation without feature eliminations I have no errors. The error came only with the command selector.fit_transform(X,y).

Comment: If I change the step and put it to a higher number the command goes through. Apparently NuSVC does not allow to recursive feature elimination with a single feature elimination. What I do not understand is: if I want to use a non linear SVC shuold I perform a data redution with the same machine or not?